# Quick way of assigning many column names(400 columns) once a column has been split in Python

Tags: python, pandas

The code below splits Colum tweet into 400 columns. However is there a way of keeping only the columns I require or a way of assigning names to the 400 columns effici so that those not required can be deleted? 
`df["tweet"].str.split('[,]', expand=True)`

Comment: How do you want to name them? `df[list(range(400))] = df["tweet"].str.split(',', expand=True)` would name the columns as integers from 0 to 399.

Comment: @ Cainã Max Couto-Silva, perfect answer. Many thanks.
Can you post the answer so I can accept it?